# Calculation mistake of diffuse coloring on pixels with multiple objects

Tags: c++, raytracing, shading

I am making a raytracer and I added diffuse coloring. Actually, it is working but if there are multiple objects in a pixel it doesn't give correct result. However, If I remove one object and render image it gives correct result. By the way, sphere is front of mesh I checked it. I mean

[image: wrong]

[image: only sphere]

It adds just ambient lighting because the diffuse color function returns zero since N.L is negative.

What can I do? I mean is it a common mistake for ray tracing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check for the part that intersects your ray with the sphere, and the plane, and returns the closest hit.

For the black pixels on the bottom sphere, the following should happen:

- calculate intersection with sphere, get back a hit with distance d0
- calculate intersection with plane, get back a hit with distance d1
- whichever distance is smaller (d0 or d1) is the hit you want to use for shading your pixel. so among your hits, find the one with minimum distance. if the distance is infinity then return the background color (black in  your case)

Comment: Yes, my bug was about that. I was finding the closest one, but I realized I wasn't using this value. I mean I was using the last intersection point. I updated my intersection point after I found the closest one and it worked